# php domxpath not working with concat functions

Tags: php, xpath

I parse url from http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/accelerative/accelerative.htm

With xpath:

```
concat( 'http://www.bodybuilding.com', //div[@class='product-details']/h3/a/@href)
```

But it not work

I tried with other query

```
//`div[@class='product-details']/h3/a[concat('abc',@href)]`
```

then it work

What's wrong In this code?

I'm using

```
Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19
DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.7.8
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show what exactly you'd like to find on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a node set to `concat()` does not work as expected. `concat()` expects it's arguments to be strings.

What about the following code?

```
$url = 'http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/accelerative/accelerative.htm';
$baseUrl = 'http://www.bodybuilding.com';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$xpath = '//div[@class="product-details"]/h3/a/@href';

foreach($selector->query($xpath) as $node) {
    var_dump($baseUrl . $node->nodeValue);
}
```

Output:

```
string(47) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/whey.html"
string(47) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/whey.html"
string(47) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/whey.html"
string(47) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/whey.html"
string(47) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/whey.html"
string(47) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/whey.html"
string(47) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/whey.html"
string(47) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/whey.html"
string(50) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/jym/pre-jym.html"
string(65) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/essential-amino-energy.html"
string(65) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/essential-amino-energy.html"
string(65) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/essential-amino-energy.html"
string(65) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/essential-amino-energy.html"
string(63) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/rsp-nutrition/quadralean.html"
string(63) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/rsp-nutrition/quadralean.html"
string(48) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/bsn/synth.html"
string(48) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/bsn/synth.html"
string(48) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/bsn/synth.html"
string(48) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/bsn/synth.html"
string(50) "http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/cellucor/c4.html"
```

Comment: You _can_ hand node sets as arguments to the `concat()` function. Then, in XPath 1.0, the following happens: If the node set only contains 1 node, its string value is concatenated with all other arguments. If the set contains more than 1 node, only the first one is evaluated to its string value and concatenated.

Comment: The fact that it is possible without a syntax is because of implicit type conversion. The documentation states: `string, string [, string ... ]`

Comment: You are right, it's a kind of conversion - but it's not really a side effect, this property of virtually all string functions is deliberate, in my opinion. But I meant something different: Currently, your answer implicitly states that the OP's XPath expression does not work because one cannot pass node sets to `concat()`.

Comment: From the OPs attempts, `concat( 'http://www.bodybuilding.com', //div[@class='product-details']/h3/a/@href)` is actually a valid XPath expression, but will only evaluate the first `href` attribute value. `//div[@class='product-details']/h3/a[concat('abc',@href)]`  retrieves all of them, but the predicate is meaningless and always true.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but I think the current wording is ok. If I would start to explain why it is not behaving as expected I would also need to explain the `DOMXpath::evaluate()` would need to be used instead of `DOMXPath::query()` *if it would working as expected* - what it never will. This would be to much imo..

Comment: I don't think we know that the OP used `DOMXPath::query()` - since they do not show any PHP code. But let's not argue further, and +1 for a correct solution that is very likely exactly what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: Thx.. Starting to realize what your really wanted to say: If it would not accept node sets at all it would be pretty useless since, almost every query will retrieve a node, set even if it contains just a single (text) node.. Something like `concat('foo', //node[@id="1"]/text())` will require that type of conversion you've mentioned.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Thanks for your answer. But what i'm looking for is: `concat( 'http://www.bodybuilding.com', //div[@class='product-details']/h3/a/@href) ` return at least 1 result, but there are empty. I used DOMXpath::evaluate().  I must use xpath only, no php code. When I put concat in [], it's work, that mean there are an concat function in `xpath`. When I put concat outsite of [], it's understand concat is an node. The same problem for `count, string`, .. all string functions of `xpath 1.0`

Comment: @MathiasMüller I using `DOM:evaluate()`

Comment: @TimNg Why did you tagged the question PHP?

Comment: @hek2mgl, xpath with java is ok, but xpath in php is not working :(

Comment: I expect Java using XPath2.0, Why can't you use PHP code?

Comment: @hek2mgl, it's a closed system, I can't change php code

Comment: Then the system isn't capable of those queries.

Comment: @TimNg Now you should really stop wasting other people's time by asking an unclear question to begin with, not reacting to my request for clarification and posting convoluted, incomprehensible comments. _Think_ for a moment, and decide what information someone unfamiliar with your problem needs (the platform, the programming language, code you already have...), let someone proofread your English, tag your question correctly.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I need to extract urls in an html page and concat with Domain name. All must done in xpath query. And it's used DOMXpath in php to do query. Thanks All